# where is kendo.bind ? kendo ui 2013 beta

Tags: mvvm, user-interface, kendo-ui, bind, beta

I can not find the function under kendo.bind kendo class. I used the beta version 2013.q1. This is a license requirement?

- With a library using require.js.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `kendo.bind` method is available in kendo.binder.min.js if you are using stand alone files.

Comment: Thanks. I have added kendo.core.min and kendo.data.min but i dont add kendo.binder.min . im now add kendo.binder.min my problem solved. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

`kendo.bind` is part of KendoUI and might be found in different files depending on your KendoUI distribution / strategy (include all, include the minified files, include sources,...).
The two most typical files where you can find it are:

1. `js/kendo.all.min.js`.
2. `js/kendo.web.min.js`.

Comment: said libraries containing each class of files. designed in a modular structure my project. For this reason I use require.js library. I used kendo libraries, kendo.core.min.js, as kendo.window.min.js modular libraries. kendo.bind be found in the libraries seems to be the most appropriate kendo.core.min.js library. but there was not. kendo.bind library are housed in the library which is modular, which I need.